# GPS Antenna Testing

Tags: antenna, gps

I want to test my GPS antenna. The problem is that my test setup is inside the room and not near to the window. It is not getting locked. Now as the setup has several connections, I can not take my device outside.

I am using UFL connector for connecting my FPC GPS Antenna.

How would I be able to test my GPS Antenna. Is there any repeaters available to test the same?

Comment: Move closer to the window?

Comment: That looks like the last option as I will need to move entire setup.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a vector signal generator and play a GPS file/scenario and transmit it through an antenna. Your GPS Rx antenna should receive it.

If you have a GPS module, it can decode your position.

Comment: vector signal generator is a costly solution. Can I use some kind of repeater that I can put on the window?

Comment: It is very difficult to handle GPS signal because it is often lower than noise floor, typically around -120dBm or less. Your repeater need to have a good LNA. There are commercially available solution, to relay it indoor. Not sure about the price.

Comment: I can see some Repeaters online but all of them have SMA connector. How will I connect it to my device? How will it be interfaced to my Antenna?

Comment: A lot of repeaters are designed for conducted test of GPS module instead of antenna. So it make sense to have an SMA conductor at the output.

If you can adjust the output power of the repeater (that is to say the repeater has an amplifier), you can connect the SMA cable of your repeater to your indoor Tx antenna (need to be way higher than -120dBm at repeater output plane).

Comment: You can also connect the repeater output to your GPS module using SMA UFL adapter (assuming your repeater dont do amplification). But that wont be testing your GPS Rx antenna.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to this similar question.
[GPS QA during manufacturing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/354439/gps-qa-during-manufacturing)

There are many answers in this thread that can let you have an understanding of the problem you're facing.